# Efficiently checking a hashed password from database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, php-password-hash

firstly I have tried my best to find a definitive answer on this. Secondly, my code appears to work, but I want to confirm I am doing this in an efficient manner and not leaving myself open to security breaches.

Firstly, I use PHP password_hash when adding user to admin table;

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO admin (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

$password = password_hash('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Secondly, when a user attempts to login, I retrieve users from the admin table by matching the username ONLY, as I couldn't see a way to check the hash during the query (this is the part I am unsure if there is a better way), and also define the $password variable from the POST input;

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    // define $password for use in password verify
    $password = $_POST['password'];
```

Thirdly, if there is a result from the query, I run password_verify on the user input to check for a match, and then I branch depending on true or false.

```
if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                session_start();
                foreach ($row as $user) {
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['id'];
                }
            } else {
                $errors = true;
            }                       
            header('location: leads.php');
        }
        else {
            $errors = true;
        }
```

I know there are many different ways to hash / secure passwords, but using the native password_hash functions is the way I decided to go, my question is have I done it right / is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see no `password_hash()` in your question. anyway, if it works, it works.

Comment: *Got hash Ralph?* I could eat @Fred-ii- [Properly Hashing & Verifying Passwords with PHP's Built-In Functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)

Comment: Use of prepared statements with bind variables, check.... use of password_hash()/password_verify(), check.... though you should only ever get one or no rows returned from the fetch, so no need to loop..... and you should probably exit after your `header` to prevent PHP continuing to execute the script any further

Comment: Got something kickin' round here somewhere *Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: And yes, you do need to retrieve the user and password from the database before you can use password_verify()

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds more like a request for a http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Even with pdo, you still need check the user input against length and other basic rules. If they are garbage, why bother sending them to db? Also I don't see any restrictions on number of login attempts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I validate with js to check values are not garbage. In terms of number of login attempts - how would you structure that exactly? Extra column, adds against username if pw is incorrect, then resets to 0 once successful login is gained?

Comment: i do exit after the header, apologies I didn't copy that in

Comment: Don't rely on js validation alone, always validate server_side as well because it's trivial to create a request that can be executed without a browser or js engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your code looks quite okay, except the things already mentioned. As you ask for improvements, especially performance related ones, here we go:

- Add an index on `username`
- If your table gets a lot of entries, remove the index from `username`, add a new column called `hash` with an index and rewrite your insert and select like this:

  `INSERT INTO admin (username, password, hash) VALUES (:username, :password, crc32(username))`

  `SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username AND hash=crc32(:username)`

I assume, you use MySQL, so adding `LIMIT 1` to your query helps the optimizer and stops searching after the row is found.

Avoiding the `foreach`-loop is also possible, if you work with just one row.

BTW: `header('location: leads.php');` should read `header('Location: leads.php');` and using absolute paths makes things more robust.

Comment: thanks for this - what do you mean by add an index? And the header line - do you mean make the L in location a capital? Is there a reason for this? Yes it's just local at the moment and I am not sure of the absolute path as I don;t know the domain

Comment: You should add an index to your database table: `ALTER TABLE admin add INDEX(username);`, which will improve performance quite a lot at the beginning (for the first 2-5M rows).

Comment: According to RFC2616, the "Location"-header has to be capital, even if most modern browsers handle it insensitive. The argument is said to be an absolute URI. If you don't have a domain yet, use an absolute path in the meantime (beginning with a / )

Comment: brilliant, thanks for that. Somebody mentioned checking unsuccessful login attempts - is there a best practice for doing this (you can see my suggestion in my comment above)

Comment: Create a new table with the IP-address as the key and insert or update the current timestamp and a counter, which you have to check when someone attempts to login.

Comment: so you'd recommend checking against the ip rather than checking against a username and a failed password?

Comment: It's not a recommendation to use the IP. The IP (or another client identification) helps against general brute force attacks. Blocking just one user might be a little annoying for certain users. Anyway, in practice a clever quota design with user & ip-quotas could be a better idea. Depends on the use case.